# How do I set up a Scratch Org with Service Setup available?

Tags: salesforcedx

I've been taking some lessons and practice developing in SalesforceDX and it's really promising. Now I have to apply the knowledge by implementing service cloud and I couldn't seem to access some service cloud setup functionality in a scratch org like the "Service Setup".

Comment: Have you checked the scratch org definition values? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm

Comment: Thanks so much, @Jeferson Chaves! That's what I was looking for. Works magic. 

Comment: Hey @ivatanDev: I will post this an answer and if that helps you do you mind to vote it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for a way to specify that you need Service Cloud in the scratch org.

That is done setting adding "ServiceCloud" on features at the scratch org definition file: `"features": ["ServiceCloud"]`.

Check the [Scratch Org Definition Configuration Values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) for more settings.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to include "ServiceUser" as well as "ServiceCloud" in the features section of the scratch org definition file to get this to work so I could access service Setup in my scratch orgs